# C# dynamic form text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an inherited form and use it as a setting form. I ask user to input name to store, I want to change form title (text property of forms) dynamically according to the input data. but if I change base form title, overflow occur. also I create FormTitle property in base form to save current form name.

for example my application name is SerenaIR and I want to show below style for all of my forms.

SerenaIR | storename | formname
ex: SerenaIR | SuperMarket | Sale

FormTitle Property

```
    private string _frmTitle;
    /// <summary>
    /// current form title for showing on title bar.
    /// </summary>
    [Category("JSCustomizer"),
     Description("The text that is displayed on form title bar.")]
    public string FormTitle
    {
        get { return _frmTitle; }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                _frmTitle = value;
                Invalidate();
                var appPreName = Properties.Settings.Default.AppNamePre + @" " + Properties.Settings.Default.AppName;

                if(_frmTitle.Length < 3)
                {
                    base.Text = appPreName;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.Text = appPreName + @" | " + _frmTitle;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

in setting form i save setting about store name and on the base form when i want change the title by below code, all of Inherited form raise error!

```
    private void JSfrmBaseLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Text = Properties.Settings.Default.AppNamePre + @" " + Properties.Settings.Default.AppName;
    }
```

Comment: can you provide some code sample as to what you have tried and isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are creating and endless loop that causes the overflow. But I think the real problem is that you are misunderstanding how inheritance works in this scenario. Changing  a non-static property value on a base form will not update the value for inheriting forms because each form is a new instance.

My suggestion is to use a property in Program.cs to store the form title. In this example I am changing the form title on a button click. All forms that inherit Form1 will set the new form title in OnLoad.

Program.cs:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        FormTitle = Properties.Settings.Default.FormTitle;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public static string FormTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Text = Program.FormTitle;
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.FormTitle = "new form title";
        Text = Program.FormTitle;
        new Form2().Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say Form2 inherited Form1, var strInput is the text input from user. Then, when newing a Form2, maybe you can write:

```
//Form1, Form2 definition
public partial class Form2 : Form1
//set Form2 title.
var strInput = "Sale";
var d2 = new Form2 {Text = base.Text + " | " + strInput};
```

Comment: I have a lot of form, and i want to change title of all inherited form by changing the store name in settings.